Why does poetry run try to create a virtual environment?
I have a Dockerfile which runs poetry install succesfully and builds the image.
FROM python:3.11-slim-bookworm as base
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y iputils-ping curl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir poetry==1.8.2


FROM base as dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock /app/
RUN  poetry install --no-interaction


FROM dependencies as application
WORKDIR /app
COPY llm_fast/*.py llm_fast/
COPY llm_fast/llmlib llm_fast/llmlib/
COPY resources resources/
COPY .env ./

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash llmuser; chown -R llmuser /home/llmuser

When I run it via docker compose that issues a poetry --venv /home/llmuser/ run python -m gunicorn -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8086 llm_fast.vectorize:app
it fails with the following error:
Creating virtualenv llm-fast-9TtSrW0h-py3.11 in /.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
virtualenv: error: argument dest: the destination . is not write-able at /

Why does poetry run try creating a virtualenv and what is it telling it to do so at / while the appplication is at /app and the user home at /home/llmuser ?

Integrating Python Poetry with Docker recommends setting ENV POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=false.

Thank you @DavidMaze, I forgot to mention that I previously tried to use RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && 
poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi, hoping this would inhibit the creation of virtual environments but still had this problem
